# Find the right Google OR-Tools algorithm

Tags: c++, or-tools, cp-sat

I have to find the set of `integers` that minimize this objective function:

[image]

The costraints are:

- every `x` must be a non-negative `integer`
- [image]

`T`, `A` and `B` are `double` known numbers.

I have been looking at the OR-Tools C++ library in order to solve this problem, specifically at the CP-SAT solver.

- Is it the right tool from such problems?
- If yes, would it be feasible to convert all the `double` to `int` in the objective function?
- If not, what else do you suggest? (I'm also open to other open source C++ libraries)

Comment: btw transparent images with black text don't play well with the dark theme

Answer (score 2):

It will fit in the CP-SAT solver. You will need to scale floating point coefficients to integers.

The objective function accepts floating point coefficients.
But (x1 + A1)^2 will propagate better if you keep it that way instead of A1^2 + 2 * A1 * x1 + x1^2. which fits into the linear with double coefficient limitation of CP-SAT, provided you use temporary variables sx1 = x1 * x1.

Then make sure to use at least 8 workers for that. (parameters num_search_workers:8).

Now, I believe there are least square solvers that are more suited for this.

Comment: Are you sure I can work with decimals inside the objective function? This is from the guide: "In order to increase computational speed, the CP-SAT solver works over the integers. This means all constraints and the objective must have integer coefficients." That would mean that by multiplying the coefficient by some n*10 to get rid of the decimal value I'd need to add a costraint to the X's to accept only integer solutions

Comment: The objective function accepts floating point coefficients with integer variables natively since the last version.

Comment: So in that case I would minimize the obj func `2A1x1 + sx1 ...` , right? How can I create the variable sx1 and impose it to be equal to x1 * x1?

Comment: use model.AddMultiplicationEquality().

Comment: But I would do `model.AddMultiplicationEquality(t1, [1000 * a1 + 1000 * x1, 1000 * a1 + 1000 * x1])`. The `model.Add(sum(1000 * bi * ai) <= 1000 * T` and `model.Minimize(sum(ti)  * 1.0 / 1e6)`